# JS Require statement leaving variable undefined

Tags: javascript, electron

I have the following require statement in my main app.js file I am attempting to spawn an Electron app from. However, the variables `app` and `BrowserWindow` are left undefined (demonstrated with a console.log() immediately following this line.

```
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron');
```

I do not receive any errors until I attempt to access `app.on();`

Keep in mind this is not code I have written but the code I am getting from the tutorial on: https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/first-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because I am a fool and was running `node app.js` not `npm start`.